# Error "xpath_search" after trying to scrape the website with "xml_find_all"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr, xml2

I'm new at R. I'm trying to scrape a [public website](http://www.sap.sp.gov.br/) which contains the number of prisioners and vacancies in prison in the state of São Paulo, in Brazil. I'm a journalist and I asked the state for these informations, but they didn't want to give them to me.

I can't get any data even when using xml_find_all(). How can I scrape the website?

```
url <- "http://www.sap.sp.gov.br/"

data <- url %>%
  httr::GET() %>%
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  xml2::xml_find_all(url, '//*[@id="wrap"]/div/ul/ul/li[3]/div/div/span[1]/b')
```

Running the code above, I have the following error:

> "Error in xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns,
>   num_results = Inf) : Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=NULL]."

The information which need to be scraped are on right side of the website.

1. Access the URL;
2. Click on "Álvaro de Carvalho";
3. Get the numbers after "Capacidade" (Capacity) and "População" (Population)
   on each prision (such as "Álvaro de Carvalho", "Andradina",
   "Araraquara" and so on).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,you cannot solve this problem using this strategy. The main website is complex and open a couple of files. You can notice one of the files is http://www.sap.sp.gov.br/js/dados-unidades.js . This js script will load all the information you need, but you will have to clean the information with string functions.